# Display different symbols in QGIS using Point Displacement renderer

Tags: qgis, point, symbology

How to display different symbols (not different in size, different in shape and color) on the same point in QGIS 2.8 using Point Displacement renderer?

I want my layout with symbols around the centroid of areas, and symbols from rule-based renderer.

For some reason it seems QGIS forces all the symbols to be the same.

[image: Instead of four red dots...]

[image: I would like, let's say, 2 red dots and one diamond and one green square (here displaced manually)]

Worse case scenario I will do it manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you render your points as you want to see them AFTER you've applied the Point Displacement renderer, you still have full access to the original renderer style through the point displacement dialogue:

[image]

In the above image you can click the 'renderer settings' button, and it opens a mini-version of the renderer dialogue box that allows you to alter the colour, size, transparency of the points as if you were styling them without the point displacement.

You can see that in my example, I have first rendered the points using a Categorized renderer, then applied point displacement, then gone back into the 'Renderer Settings' and applied a size scale to the points...