# Overlapping symbol in print layout in QGIS

Tags: qgis, overlapping-features

I am working on water network map in QGIS. I've a layer with different types closely spaced of symbols.

[image]

For exporting the map, when i zoom out the map some symbols overlapped with each other & the map looked messy.

[image]

Is there any way to show all symbols clearly in the map?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the point displacement renderer to style your point layer: if tow points overlap, the symbols will be displaced (around a circle) in a way that all of them show without overlap. See here for more information: [Display different symbols in QGIS using Point Displacement renderer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/152202/display-different-symbols-in-qgis-using-point-displacement-renderer)

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In this process, the symbol displaced around a circle. Is it possible to keep them in the same line?

Comment: Not that I know. But maybe you open a new question for that, hopefully someone else knows an answer